# How to filter required rows with MySQL

Tags: mysql

Dear all: After having fetched all ranges that overlap within the table below:

RANGES

```
| Count | Status  | Begin      | End  |        Comment               | 
|  1    | used    | 1001       | 1095 | overlaps with ranges 2, 3    |                            
|  2    | hold    | 1005       | 1030 | overlaps with ranges 1, 3    |                
|  3    | unused  | 1017       | 1020 | overlaps with ranges 1, 2    |             
|  4    | used    | 1110       | 1125 | no overlap                   |
```

by using:

```
select r1.count, r1.begin, r1.end,
       group_concat(r2.count order by r2.count) as overlaps
from ranges r1 left join
     ranges r2
     on r1.end >= r2.begin and
        r1.begin <= r2.end and
        r1.count <> r2.count
group by r1.count, r1.begin, r1.end;
```

I am now left with some extra info that I would like to avoid such as:

(a) rows with status='unused'

(b) rows, where no overlap occur

Do you know how to avoid/filter (a) and (b), after range overlaps are found?

Comment: Didnt we see this question earlir today already? If it was closed then you should take that as notice that you need to improve the question, possibly showing that you have at least made an attempt to work out how to do this for yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not absoluten sure if I understood you correct but for me it seems you are looking for something like this?

```
select r1.count, r1.begin, r1.end,
   group_concat(r2.count order by r2.count) as overlaps
from ranges r1 
left join ranges r2
     on r1.end >= r2.begin and
        r1.begin <= r2.end and
        r1.count <> r2.count and
        r2.status <> 'unused'
where r1.Count IS NOT NULL and r1.status <> 'unused'
group by r1.count, r1.begin, r1.end;
```